# Jboss JDG node not joining cluster

Tags: datagrid, jboss, infinispan

We have a JDG cluster with five nodes

After we start each of the node in the cluster , one of the nodes is throwing the below message

```
05:56:11,591 WARN  [org.infinispan.partionhandling.impl.PreferAvailabilityStrategy] (undefined) ISPN000314: Cache MYCACHE lost at least half of the stable members, possible split brain causing data inconsistency. Current members are [node13/myCacheManager], lost members are [node11/myCacheManager, node12/myCacheManager, node14/myCacheManager, node10/myCacheManager], stable members are [node13/myCacheManager, node11/myCacheManager, node12/myCacheManager, node14/myCacheManager, node10/myCacheManager]
```

Looks like this node is not becoming a member of the cluster . It is still serving the client requests but not in sync with other nodes in the cluster

What could be the reason why one of the five nodes is not able to join the cluster ?

Comment: Could you please upload the log of each server with DEBUG logs for the package org.infinispan ?

Comment: More often than not this is caused by network configuration/layout issues. JGroups is the technology we use for the cluster communication. Its [manual](http://jgroups.org/manual/#TestingTheSetup) explains how to test the set up and what to do if it doesn't work. For example, if having issues with UDP you can try TCP...

Comment: one of the node was getting out of the cluster after every restart . We replaced that node from another machine and now its ok.  But we are still not able to increase the number of nodes from 5 to 7 . When we do that , we get the same issue .

Comment: as mentioned without logfiles we can not help much. Did you have TCP or UDP enabled? How is your network topology. In any case there is a JGroups test to ensure UDP is working, you can use it parallel to your ISPN instances